# The values on the x and y axes of my graph in R Studio are overlapping

Tags: r, graph, overlap

The *x*- and *y* axis tick labels are overlapping in RStudio.  My code is as follows:

```r
ggplot(data1_df, aes(x = Date, y = CO2, group = State, colour = State)) +
    geom_line() +  
    xlab("Year") +
    ylab("CO2 Emissions") +
    ggtitle("CO2 Emissions by State, 1970-2020")
```

Here is my graph:

[image]

Here are my `CO2` values:

[image]

Comment: Can you please share your data using `dput()` if possible? It makes it easier for others to run your example if we know what `data1_df` looks like.

Comment: Do you get your expected outcome if you use `ggplot(data1_df, aes(x = factor(Date), y = as.numeric(CO2), group = State, colour = State)) +`?

Comment: Looks like the issue is that both `Date` and `CO2` are variables of type character (or possibly factor). If you convert the first to type Date and the second to type numeric (or ensure they are of those types when the data is read into R), the chart should look better.

Comment: @neilfws Thanks for your support, Dear neilfws. Now I see the logic of it.

Comment: @jared_mamrot Thank you for support. You're great. Everything is good now. 


`ggplot(data1_df, aes(x = Date, y = as.numeric(CO2), group = State, color = State)) + geom_line() + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1970, 2020), breaks = seq(1970, 2020, by = 5)) + xlab("Yıl") + ylab("CO2 Emisyonları") + ggtitle("Devletlere Göre CO2 Emisyonları, 1970-2020")`